# почему не работает маршалинг vb .net

Tags: .net, visual-basic

```
 <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> Public Structure error_last_msg
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=512)> Public data() As Byte
End Structure


si = Marshal.SizeOf(error_last_msg1)
Dim error_last_msg1_ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(si)   
    i = PassThruGetLastError(error_last_msg1_ptr)
Dim s As String = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(error_last_msg1_ptr, 512)
```

почему крашится на чтении из памяти?

> System.AccessViolationException: Попытка чтения или записи в
>   защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память
>   повреждена.    в
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr ptr,
>   Int32 len)    в
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(IntPtr ptr,
>   Int32 len)

Comment: Здесь в последней строчке 512 -- это "number of characters to copy", и символы трактуются как Unicode судя по стеку => вы пытаетесь читать 512 символов = 1024 байт вместо 512 байт.

Comment: Я пробовал вместо авто ставить анси результат того же